# Getting HttpServerErrorException: 500 null when using @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am not getting this. I have a `@RestController` which is supposed to handle requests like `/foo?latitude=15.12345`. Of course there should be more parameters, but it's not even working for *one*.

This is the controller:

```
@RestController
public class GooglePlaceController {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(GooglePlaceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaceService googlePlaceService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<GooglePlaceEntity> doNearbySearch(@PathVariable Float latitude) {
        LOGGER.trace("Searching for places nearby.");
        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is the request I am building:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<PlaceDto>> nearbySearch(Float lat, Float lng, Integer radius, Boolean googleSearch) {

    String href = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8081/foo")
            .queryParam("latitude", lat)
            .build().encode().toString();

    ResponseEntity<Object> forEntity = this.oauthRestTemplate.getForEntity(href, null, Object.class);

    return null;
}
```

However, I am getting this exception below, *unless I remove `@PathVariable Float latitude` in which case the request gets handled correctly*.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:361)
    at mz.api.client.Client.nearbySearch(Client.java:191)
```

**But here is the thing:**

In another controller I am having this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/groups/{groupId}/places", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<PlaceEntity> getGooglePlaces(@PathVariable Long groupId) {
    return this.userGroupService.getPlaces(groupId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/groups/{groupId}/google-places", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addGooglePlace(@PathVariable Long groupId, @RequestParam String googlePlaceId) {
    this.userGroupService.addGooglePlace(groupId, googlePlaceId);
}
```

and those requests are working without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PathVariable` is for parameters which are part of the URL like: `/groups/{groupId}/google-places`.

If parameter is after the `?` you should use `@RequestParam` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<GooglePlaceEntity> doNearbySearch(@RequestParam Float latitude) {
    LOGGER.trace("Searching for places nearby.");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You know: "Den Wald vor lauter Bäumen nicht mehr sehen!" - Thank you

Comment: Happens to the best!